# Сreate a shared_ptr from a unique_ptr containing the structure

Tags: c++

I have a class containing such a structure:

```
class Store {

private:
    struct pointNode {
        T data;
        std::unique_ptr<pointNode> next;

        pointNode():data(std::move(T{})),next(std::move(std::unique_ptr<pointNode>{})){}
        pointNode(T n_data, std::unique_ptr<pointNode> ptr) : data(std::move(n_data)), next(std::move(ptr)) {}
    };
    std::unique_ptr<pointNode> head;
public:
     decltype(auto) Begin() ;
};
```

I need to create a Begin function that will get a pointer to head.
I wrote something like this:

```
template<typename T>
decltype(auto) Stack<T>::Begin() 
{
    std::shared_ptr<pointNode> sh_ptr=std::make_shared<pointNode>(head);
    return std::move(sh_ptr);
}
```

That is, create a shared_ptr and return it from the function, then go through the list.
But:

```
std::shared_ptr<pointNode> sh_ptr=std::make_shared<pointNode>(head);
```

returns error C2664

```
Error C2664 "Stack<int>::pointNode::pointNode(Stack<int>::pointNode &&)": 
argument 1 cannot be converted  from "std::unique_ptr<Stack<int>::pointNode,std::default_delete<Stack<int>::pointNode>>" 
in "const Stack<int>::pointNode &"
```

I tried to remove decltype (auto), but everything is the same .Maybe someone understands what I'm doing wrong .I would be happy to help, thank you

Comment: What do you think is the idea of a unique_ptr? If you can share the ownership to other pointers, you violate the core idea of a unique_ptr as it is not longer unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unique_ptr` cannot share the data with `shared_ptr`. That's the point of a *unique* pointer. But if you want to transfer the ownership, you can do it like so:

```
#include <string>
#include <memory>

int main()
{
  std::unique_ptr<std::string> up( new std::string("Hello, World!\n") );
  // up owns the object

  // Transfer ownership
  std::shared_ptr<std::string> sp( up.release() );
  // sp owns the object, up is empty.
}
```

---

Having said that, returning a `shared_ptr` from the `begin()` function is likely not what you want. I would guess that you want to return a reference or an iterator from that function. Here's how you can return a reference:

```
template<typename T>
pointNode& Stack<T>::begin() 
{
    return *head;
}
```

Note that, for this to work like STL iterators, you need to create a new iterator type. `begin` returning a refence to a private node class is not a great interface and leaks implementation details.

Comment: is there any way to return the unique_ptr so that it won't be deleted later?Because, as I understand it, if I move it,it will delete all the data after the completion of the function that called Begin ().

Comment: @Alpharius it's not clear to me that what you want to do with that `Begin()` function. Do you want it to return a simple refence to an object in the container, or do you want it to extract the object out of the container and transfer the ownership to the caller?

Comment: @ AyxanHaqverdili which is similar to simulating an iterator.
for(auto temp= temp_obj.Begin();temp!= temp_obj.End();temp++).
That is, get a pointer/reference to head in the temp and run through the list ,but I don't understand how to pass head

Comment: @ AyxanHaqverdili  A strange moment .I can write: store_obj.Begin();
But : auto temp = store_obj.Begin (); returns error E1776 " The function cannot be referenced because it is a remote function"

Comment: @Alpharius Yes, you cannot copy that node object as it stands because its copy-constructor is deleted. You can do `auto& temp = store_obj.Begin ();`

Comment: thank you very much for your help.Just could you help me understand:* head will return essentially the pointNode type.So why "auto temp=a. Begin ();" doesn't work without a reference ,i.e. why the copying pointNode constructor is removed.Thanks again

Comment: @Alpharius `pointNode` has a member of type `unique_ptr`, and this type cannot be copied (because it's a unique-ownership). For this reason, the whole class cannot be copied. To cope with that, I suggest you implement an iterator type, a lot like iterators in STL containers. Google iterators if you want to learn more.

Answer (score 1):

`unique_ptr`s claim unique ownership. The clean way to transfer ownership to a `shared_ptr` would be to *move* it. So if you have

```
std::unique_ptr<pointNode> head;
```

then

```
std::shared_ptr<pointNode> sh_ptr( std::move(head) );
```

This is however a design flaw.

You do not want to transfer ownership of the container's elements. Here you actually want to share the raw pointer with the iterator. Any iterator that you have should be able to use that raw pointer - but not destroy the element it points at.

The first draft of a simple forward list type of container would be something like the below - and nowhere should a `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr` be used:

```
template<class T>
class Store {
private:
    struct Node {
        T data;
        Node* next;
    };

    Node* head = nullptr;

public:
    struct iterator {
        iterator(Node* x = nullptr) : current(x) {}

        T& operator*() { return current->data; }
        T* operator->() { return &current->data; }
        
        iterator& operator++() { current = current->next; return *this; }

        bool operator!=(const iterator& rhs) const {
            return current != rhs.current;
        }

    private:
        Node* current;
    };

    ~Store() {
        Node* next;
        while(head) {
            next = head->next;
            delete head;
            head = next;
        }
    }
    iterator begin() { return head; }
    iterator end() { return nullptr; }
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/fEaYdx)

Comment: is there any way to return the unique_ptr so that it won't be deleted later?Because, as I understand it, if I move it,it will delete all the data after the completion of the function that called Begin ().

Comment: @Alpharius _If_ you return a `unique_ptr` you've given up the ownership of whatever resource the pointer is pointing at. It doesn't matter how you go about doing it (unless you provide an odd _deleter_ to the `unique_ptr`). A `unique_ptr` _will_ `delete` (or `delete[]`) whatever it is pointing at at the end of its own lifetime. You do _not_ want that for an iterator. The proper way to create an iterator is to make a small class that carries the pointer and is able to provide a reference or pointer to the data it's pointing at to the user of the iterator.

Comment: Well,thanks,i need to try,but even if you create a class, you still need to somehow pass a pointer to the data (which will be deleted), or apparently you need to copy the data into it

Comment: @Alpharius You need to pass a pointer to the data, yes, but a _raw_ pointer. The iterator has no business deleting it when the iterator dies. That's the job of the container class. No copying of the actual data should ever be made in a normal iterator. An iterator should be really cheap to copy - and it will be, if it only contains a raw pointer.

Comment: thank you so much for your hard work.Yes, it's easier to just use a pointer here,I just wanted to practice with smart pointers :)

Comment: @Alpharius You're welcome! I get that you are experimenting, but you picked one of the few times where a raw pointer is actually preferable. :-)